# When am trying to change my number on Sumsung Galaxy A5 it's "unknown". And I can't also make a call with the current number

Tags: sms

What do I have do to be able to change my number and also to make a call?

Answer (score 0):

If you also can't make a call, it sounds like a problem with the SIM card. You should contact your carrier and ask them for help. They might need to send you a new SIM card.